# Content not sizing to modal window until browser window resize

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I'm trying to place dynamic content in a modal (popup) but they're not sizing properly. However, if I have the popup open and resize my browser window, they kick into place. The content is clearly sizing to the hidden div prior to opening the modal. How can I fix this? I'm assuming jQuery is the way to go?

Below is a screenshot of what I'm facing. The top part of the photo is what appears when I click the link to open the modal & the bottom pick is what happens after I resize my window (which is what I'm after).

Here's the click event code.

```
// Lightbox Link
            $(context).on('click', ThemifyGallery.config.lightbox, function(event){
                event.preventDefault();
                var $self = $(this),
                    $link = ( $self.find( '> a' ).length > 0 ) ? $self.find( '> a' ).attr( 'href' ) : $self.attr('href'),
                    $type = ThemifyGallery.getFileType($link),
                    $title = (typeof $(this).children('img').attr('alt') !== 'undefined') ? $(this).children('img').attr('alt') : $(this).attr('title'),
                    $iframe_width = (ThemifyGallery.isVideo($link)) ? '100%' : (ThemifyGallery.getParam('width', $link)) ? ThemifyGallery.getParam('width', $link) : '700',
                    $iframe_height = (ThemifyGallery.isVideo($link)) ? '100%' : (ThemifyGallery.getParam('height', $link)) ? ThemifyGallery.getParam('height', $link) : '100%';
                    if($iframe_width.indexOf("%") == -1) $iframe_width += 'px';
                    if($iframe_height.indexOf("%") == -1) $iframe_height += 'px';

                if( ThemifyGallery.isYoutube( $link ) ) {
                    // for youtube videos, sanitize the URL properly
                    $link = ThemifyGallery.getYoutubePath( $link );
                }
                var $args = {
                    items: {
                        src: $link,
                        title: $title
                    },
                    type: $type,
                    iframe: {
                        markup: '<div class="mfp-iframe-scaler" style="max-width: '+$iframe_width+' !important; height: '+$iframe_height+';">'+
                        '<div class="mfp-close"></div>'+
                        '<div class="mfp-iframe-wrapper">'+
                        '<iframe class="mfp-iframe" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>'+
                        '</div>'+
                        '</div>'
                    }
                };
                if($self.find('img').length > 0) {
                    $.extend( $args, {
                        mainClass: 'mfp-with-zoom',
                        zoom: {
                            enabled: true,
                            duration: 300,
                            easing: 'ease-in-out',
                            opener: function() {
                                return $self.find('img');
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
                if(ThemifyGallery.isVideo($link)){
                    $args['mainClass'] += ' video-frame';
                } else {
                    $args['mainClass'] += ' standard-frame';
                }
                if(ThemifyGallery.isInIframe()) {
                    window.parent.jQuery.magnificPopup.open($args);
                } else {
                    $.magnificPopup.open($args);
                    $(window).trigger('resize');
                }
            });
```

I did add `$(window).trigger('resize');` and it works great! I just need to implement it in my own scripts.js so it's not overwritten someday.

Thanks again,

Mike

[Content not sizing to modal window until browser window resize](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e7rJ2.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If window `resize` event can fix your problem, then you can simply trigger the event after you show your modal form by this (in jQuery):

```
 $(window).trigger('resize');
```

Further debugging requires your actual HTML markups and JS codes.

Comment: Thanks zero point! Page [link](http://inkgds.ca/dev/themify-stonehammer-4/experience-provider/daytripping-outdoor-adventures/). The modal is loaded by the Feature Activities button about half way down the page. Based on my research I narrowed it down to the same trigger resize code you provided. I guess I'm lost on where & how I need to call it. What id/class am I targeting? Can I just drop the code in my scripts.js with my other functions? Pretty sure it's using Magnific Popup.

Thanks again!

Comment: @macmike78: I think you show your modal form on a button click or something in a JS file. I checked out the link, it will take time to find the click event which fires modal form. Go ahead and find the piece of code and add it to your question. But this is how it works in most cases, such as Bootstrap modal forms. You find that click event and add this one line of code at the end of the event, when modal form is already shown.

Comment: Almost there! I found the click event. Prob being is that I need to hook into it (overwrite it in my own scripts.js since this one will likely be overwritten someday). Can you tell from the code if I can call on that function? I did add your code to the bottom as you can see and it works. As I said, I just can't leave it there. Thanks!

Comment: @macmike78: Can you please paste that part of the code in your question? the click event code and the line you have added.

Comment: I edited my original post to include the code. After much tinkering and research I eventually got it working 2 different ways...
`(function ($) {
    $.magnificPopup.instance.open = function (data) {
        $.magnificPopup.proto.open.call(this, data);
        $(window).trigger('resize');
    };
})(jQuery);`
and
`(function ($) {
    $(document).on('mfpOpen', function () {
        $(window).trigger('resize');
    })
})(jQuery);`

Thanks so much for your help! You put me on the right path. Much appreciated zero point.